# Exporting a table with BLOB to a .csv file actually showing the text in it (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

when I try to export the following table

[image]

to a .csv file I get "..." whenever there is a BLOB field. It is crucial that the .csv file contains the actual data inside the BLOB field (it is a large text).

How can I achieve that?

Below is the exported .csv file (showing the "..." fields)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Are you exporting table data or your result set data? See here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-results.html

I think that if you make a select query in your table and then try to export to CSV you should get the data.

Comment: I am exporting the result set data Renato.